# Как сделать перетаскиваемые строки в таблице rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drag-n-drop

Я несколько дней ищу информацию о перетаскивании строк в таблице, так чтобы это работало при заполнении с помощью `each do` на странице. При этом я не могу добавить в таблицу бд, из которой я беру данные никаких колонок, как иногда советуют.

В общем смысле у меня есть таблица Tasks, которая ссылается на некоторые другие таблицы. (пробовал заполнять по типу: <%=task.project(s).name%> - так не работает)

Перепробовал много вариантов. Вариант с acts_as_list отдельно и вместе с sortablejs и stimulus, при добавлении колонки position. Пробовал и вариант c добавлением колонки sort с гемами ...jquery и rails-sortable(что-то вроде), и ещё несколько.

Однако, ни один из этих вариантов даже наглядно не позволил притронуться к строкам таблицы. Может дело в том, что я пишу плагин в приложении...

В всего двух варинтах(один из которых представлен ниже), хотя бы визуально выходит взять строку, но при отпускании она просто встаёт на место.

**Моё представление**

```
<form method="GET">
  <select name="filter_option" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="">
      Выберите пользователя
    </option>
    <option value="0">
      Все
    </option>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <option value="<%=user.id%>"><%= user.name %>
      </option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</form>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tasks</th>
      <th>Номер</th>
      <th>Проект</th>
      <th>Трекер</th>
      <th>Статус</th>
      <th>Тема</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tbody class="sort">
      <tr id=<%=task.position%>>
        <td><%= task.position %></td>
        <% @t = @issues.find_by(id: task.issues_id) %>
        <td><%= @t.id %></td>
        <% @project = @projects.find_by(id: task.projects_id) %>
        <td><%= @project.name %></td>
        <% @tracker = @trackers.find_by(id: task.trackers_id) %>
        <td><%= @tracker.name %></td>
        <% @status = @statuses.find_by(id: task.issue_statuses_id) %>
        <td><%= @status.name %></td>
        <td><%= @t.subject %></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>

<script>
  $('.sort').sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    axis:   'y',
    update: function(e, ui) {
        href = 'tasks';
        $(this).sortable("refresh");
        sorted = $(this).sortable("serialize", 'id');
        $.ajax({
            type:   'POST',
            url:    href,
            data:   sorted,
            success: function(msg) {
                //do something with the sorted data
            }
        });
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Если при итерации переменную назвать в единственном числе, читать код станет сильно проще `@issues.each do |issue| ... <%= issue.id %> <%= issue.project.name %> ...` (последнее будет работать, если связь в модели прописана).

Comment: А почему именно айдишник менять? Не самая лучшая идея, честно говоря. Судя по вашему прошлому вопросу, в таблице есть поля lft/rgt - может быть их можно использовать?

Comment: У вас на фронте есть какой-то фреймворк (реакт-ангуляр-вот-это-вот-всё)? Или хотя бы старый добрые jquery? Суть решения в том, чтобы прикрутить подходящий готовый плагин на фронт для перетаскивания строк и на его событие отправлять запрос на бэк в отдельный экшн контроллера

Comment: Я сейчас думал с помощью acts_as_list попробовать. Пока не очень получается, пытаюсь глубже изучить, чтобы понять что там и как

Comment: Да, как вариант можно acts_as_list использовать, если получится подружить его с имеющейся таблицей

Comment: Пока пытаюсь тут разобраться https://www.kindleman.com.au/blog/drag-and-drop-with-rails-and-html5/. Вроде выглядит не очень сложно, однако, я местами всё ещё не понимаю.

Comment: В итоге то и получается, что максимум из всего, что я нашёл - могу только строки тоскать, но они при отпускании на место возвращаются. Обновил вопрос